# Using Command design pattern to eliminate duplicate code

Tags: python, design-patterns

Let's say I have a program which can create and delete files. And I have 2 different ways of doing that - either execute external utilities, which already deal with these actions, or implement the creation and deletion from within my program. I want to have the choice of both and select the appropriate one dynamically, during runtime. So I would have interfaces and implementations similar to this:

```
class IFile:
    def create():
        pass

    def delete():
        pass

class ExecFile(IFile):
    def create():
        # Call an external executable

    def delete():
        # Call an external executable

class ImplFile(IFile):
    def create():
        # Implement creation of the file

    def delete():
        # Implement deletion of the file
```

This way, I can select either of them during runtime and use it. But what if I decide to create another implementation, which is a mix between `ExecFile` and `ImplFile`, therefore the `create()` function will be the same as in `ExecFile` but delete the same as in `ImplFile` (or some combination of them). I thought of solving this problem using the command design pattern and do something like the following:

```
class IFile:
    def create():
        pass

    def delete():
        pass

class IFileAction:
    def exec():
        pass

class ExecCreateFile(IFileAction):
    def exec():
         # Call an external executable to create file

class ImplCreateFile(IFileAction):
    def exec():
        # Implement creation of the file

class ExecDeleteFile(IFileAction):
    def exec():
         # Call an external executable to delete file

class ImplDeleteFile(IFileAction):
    def exec():
        # Implement deletion of the file


class ExecFile(IFile):
    def create():
        ExecCreateFile().exec()

    def delete():
        ExecDeleteFile().exec()


class ImplFileIFile(IFile):
    def create():
        ImplCreateFile().exec()

    def delete():
        ImplDeleteFile().exec()


class ExecImplFile(IFile):
    def create():
        ExecCreateFile().exec()

    def delete():   
        ImplDeleteFile().exec()
```

Question: Would it be appropriate to use this design pattern in this particular case, or something better could be done? My only concern here is that if the example was more sophisticated, let's say I added an option to get file size, get file owner, etc..., I would end up creating multiple classes of type IFileAction, which basically perform only one action.

P.S This might be a bad example, but couldn't think of anything better. Also, the question does not particularly refer to Python, just used it to represent the example.

Comment: Your `IFileAction` class is completely useless. All of its subclasses should just be functions.

Answer (score 0):

Compositor is the answer. 
You have to preserve the interface, while implemantation consumes both instances (via the constructor typically) - and triggers appropriate methods on them.